# Jenkins Setup Wizard Blank Page

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have just installed Jenkins on my RHEL 6.0 server via npm:

```
npm -ivh jenkins-2.7.2-1.1.noarch.rpm
```

I have also configured my port to be 9917 to avoid clashing with my Tomcat server, allowing me to access the Jenkins page at `ipaddress:9917`. After entering the initial admin password at the **Unlock Jenkins** page, I am presented with a blank page, with the header "SetupWizard [Jenkins]".

Anyone knows why am I getting a blank page, and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that after I opened the port 9917 in my firewall,the blank pages error stopped and I can continue with the setup just fine.

Comment: same problem using official jenkins docker image ... with no root access, just the jenkins user available .. Any clue of how to do ? specific question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300475/jenkins-setup-wizard-blank

Comment: How does opening a firewall port that Jenkins does not use solve a Jenkins issue? Jenkins listens on port 8080 by default. Did you manually configure your Jenkins instance to listen specifically on port 9917?

Comment: false positive ? didn't you restart anything ?

Answer (score 51):

I experienced the same problem but a simple restart fixed it .

Just try this :-

```
sudo service jenkins stop
sudo service jenkins start
```

Comment: What a buggy software and poor documentation. Had installed jenkins as per https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#setup-wizard, didn't find log in the path mentioned in this document nor https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging#Logging-MacOSX

Comment: On a single line, you have two options now: in non-systemd systems use `sudo service jenkins restart`; in systemd-based distros `sudo systemd restart jenkins.service`

Comment: On Windows, simply opening http://localhost:8080/safeRestart solved the problem for me.

Comment: On Windows, restarting the service from the service manager resolved the issue.

Comment: In my case, I restarted gave the full permission to the whole directory, the service and restart the even virtual machine, but didn't work. After just reinstalled it worked fine without any effort...

Answer (score 20):

targeting the url to https://../jenkins/index
appeared to solve the problem in most cases.

even if the first time, Browser's back button once on the blank page after the wizard finished sent me to the working page: http//:websiteDomain/login?from=%2

In my case I used (jenkins/jenkins lts) the [official docker image](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: I have tried: `http://localhost:8080/index` and it worked, thanks for hint @user1767316

Answer (score 9):

After getting Jenkins Setup Wizard Blank Page http://localhost:8080/index works for me.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue, but I am using the default port 8080. I installed jenkins in this way: 
 `yum install jenkins`

Then I executed:

```
systemctl start.jenkins
systemctl enable.jenkins
```

then allow 8080 on the firewall:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

And the part that was missing (at least for me) was :

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

After that the installation came normally. I Hope this can be usefull for someone else.

cheers

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue on macOS Sierra 10.12 and just had to restart the daemon.

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

Answer (score 3):

I too had same problem. But I'm using jenkins in docker container. So i did below after that it started to work.

```
docker stop my_container_name
docker start my_container_name
```

For your case, you should restart your jenkins if you are using linux

```
sudo service jenkins stop
sudo service jenkins start
```

Comment: Worked for me - docker in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Stopping and starting jenkins service made it work for me in windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Windows. I went to the Windows Services and found Jenkins there as a service. I stopped the service and started again and then I could see the page.

Comment: Though my service was working but I simply restarted it again and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem

**Restarting the service fixed it**

```
sudo systemctl stop jenkins 
sudo systemctl start jenkins 
sudo systemctl status jenkins
```

Try with make a request to you jenkins url

```
curl http://<your jenkins host>:<your port>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fixe it by changing the port.(windows10)

First you open the command line and proceed to:

cd ..

cd ..

cd "Program Files (x86)"     (or wherever you have the jenkins folder)

cd jenkins

dir

java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081

by doing this you´re changing jenkins localhost port from 8080 to 8081 avoiding any conflits.

Warning :do not close the command line after its done , make sure its open before you enter localhost:8081

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, same as Linux, I had to stop/start `jenkins` service to make it work

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/my.jenkins.plist 
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/my.jenkins.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happened to run Jenkins using generic Java war file, a restart will be required after finishing installation. Stop the java (using Ctrl+C if you on shell), then start again using

```
$ java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=3001
```

Note: My jenkins run on port 3001

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this problem was corrected in 2.195, thanks to Bogdan Sukonnov in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59017.