# Jenkins - Setup wizard blank?

Tags: jenkins, installation, jenkins-plugins

I have tried to setup a docker image with Jenkins installed - I used the wizard, and got the initial password entered, and installed the recommended plugins - After that, I only get an blank page when I connecto to the localhost:8080 page 
[Jenkins inital page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDoNv.png)

If I connect to something like localhost:8080/configure The page works fine, but the inital page doesn't - The tab is called "SetupWizard" in firefox - What can I do?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966105/jenkins-setup-wizard-blank-page

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me after the initial installation, in the fisrt time starting.

Restart the jenkins instance by

http://jenkins.server/restart

and after that the home page should be working.

Comment: this one worked so well. It works for Jenkins installation with docker

Answer (score 1):

A click on browser's "back button" sent me to 
the working page: /login?from=%2F ....

historical:
A non docker-image-related answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966105/jenkins-setup-wizard-blank-page)
It suggests a firewall setting.

But is such a setting modification possible 
on the [official jenkins docker image](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md) (jenkins/jenkins lts)
using the provided jenkins user with no root access ?

(I personaly started the docker image ussing this command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name jenkins --hostname jenkins --add-host ns375278:172.17.0.1 -e JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins" -e JENKINS_ARGS="--prefix=/jenkins" --env "JAVA_OPTS=-Dhudson.footerURL=https://myDnsName.com"  jenkins/jenkins:tls
```

Comment: later found default admin jenkins password location:

    docker exec jenkins-master cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword

Comment: And the way to become root: docker exec -u root -ti e33f6adb3ffb /bin/bash